# cannot access files in appbase's subfolder in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a very simple Tomcat web app.

This app is deployed to ${catalina.home}/webapps/myapp. Under myapp there are two folders:
1. WEB-INF - contains a single web.xml file with bare minimal content.
2. document - contains a folder called data.

My goal is to access any files under document folder.

Now I can access files under document folder without problem. i.e. open `http://hostname:8080/myapp/document/abc.txt` in browser will show the text file content.

But I can't access files under document/data, i.e, open `http://hostname:8080/myapp/document/data/xyz.txt` in browser will get 404 error.

Is there any configuration that I missed? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Based on what you posted, it should work.  Maybe there's something else in this webapp that's preventing it from working.  Can you post you your web.xml?  Also, are both files actually text files? If you move the abc file to the data dir can you access it with http://hostname:8080/myapp/document/data/abc.txt ? Finally, is the xyz.txt file in the data directory and readable by the user that's running the Tomcat process?

Comment: Andres, thanks for your response. I got it working finally. I think it was the web.xml. Unfortunately I deleted the old web.xml, so I don't know what was wrong about it. How I fix it was I deleted the old WEB-INF then copied the ${catalina.home}/webapps/docs/WEB-INF to myapp/. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved. I believe the problem was the web.xml. What I did was copying the sample web.xml from tomcat/webapps/docs/WEB-INF.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because my URL pattern didn't include anything but the root directory

I changed this in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>webdav</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

to this

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>webdav</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

(I added a star after the slash in the url-pattern)